# ServiceStack JsonSerializer DeserializeFromString is removing double quotes

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

This is a simplified version of a deeper nested json object that i am working on, and here is an issue I have encountered.

---

First try, As shown in the picture, when I call `DeserializeFromString<T>()` I am getting doc1 and doc2 html code but the quotation marks from the original `var str1` are gone.

***pic1.***
[image]

---

Second try, now I break down the "documents" from `string` -> to `Dictionary<string, string>` to see what happen. The parsing has gone wrong as you can see in the debug view in the 2nd pic.

***pic2.***
[image]

---

How I can keep my "double quotes" in my string values? How do I make it parse correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your JSON is basically invalid because, if you remove the string-escaping for C#, you get:

```
"doc1":"<font color="black">hello ...
```

Which means as far as JSON is concerned your string ends before 'black'. You might need to double-escape the \

```
var str = "... \"doc1\":\"<font color=\\\"black\\\">hello ...";
```

Comment: oh i see my problem. Thanks